# Adding a column to a model at runtime (without additional tables) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to give admins of my web application the ability to add some new fields to a model. The model is called Artwork and i would like to add, for instante, a test_column column at runtime. I'm just teting, so i added a simple link to do it, it will be of course parametric.

I managed to do it through migrations:

```
  def test_migration_create  
   Artwork.add_column :test_column, :integer
    flash[:notice] = "Added Column test_column to artworks"
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  end

  def test_migration_delete
    Artwork.remove_column :test_column
    flash[:notice] = "Removed column test_column from artworks"
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  end
```

It works, the column gets added/ removed to/from the databse  without issues. I'm using active_scaffold at the moment, so i get the test_column field in the form without adding anything. When i submit a create or an update, however, the test_column does not get updated and stay empty. Inspecting the parameters, i can see:

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update", "authenticity_token"=>"37Bo5pT2jeoXtyY1HgkEdIhglhz8iQL0i3XAx7vu9H4=", "id"=>"62", "record"=>{"number"=>"test_artwork", "author"=>"", "title"=>"Opera di Test", "test_column"=>"TEEST", "year"=>"", "description"=>""}}
```

the test_column parameter is passed correctly. So why active record keeps ignoring it? I tried to restart the server too without success.

I'm using ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.5, and mongrel with an sqlite3 database.

Thanks

Comment: closing, i was treating the column as a string rather then as an integer. 

Artwork.add_column :test_column, :string

did the trick.
Leaving the message here for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the development environment, ActiveRecord models reload their metadata upon every request. In the production environment, however, metadata is cached at startup, so any columns you add will not be easily accessible until that metadata is refreshed.

Also, altering a table usually requires an exclusive table lock while the data is rewritten, which could really hurt your site's performance.

Comment: I thought something like that. Performances should not be really an issue. My idea is to make this function available only to admins and the operation will made only a few times to setup data.

Anyway, do you have any advice on a better way to design a similar behaviour? Maybe i should use a separate table for additional attributes. Any link to a good implementation of it?

Or, alternatively, can i force the refresh of the metadata in production mode somehow?

Thanks